# ASP.Net Core MVC - Auth Context different for partial views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Model that produces 2 partial views.

- One partial view contains a form to change your username
- The other contains a form to change your password

Both forms reach back to a POST method in the `UserController`. Each section, independently works fine. However, if I change the username and then try to change the password, the Auth Context contains the old username and I encounter an error.

The logic goes a little like this...

---

#### Change Username

Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeUsername(ChangeUsernameViewModel model) {
    string oldUsername = model.OldUsername;
    string newUsername = model.NewUsername;

    User user = await this.UserService.GetUserById(this.Authorization.UserId);

    if (user != null)
    {
        // Update username in DB
        User user = await this.UserService.ChangeUsername(user, newUsername);

        // Update cookie
        this._owinContext.Authentication.SignIn(this.Authorization.ToClaimsIdentity());

        // Update ViewModel
        model.OldUsername = newUsername;
        model.NewUsername = string.Empty();
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Service

```
public async Task<User> ChangeUsername(User user, string newUsername) {
    // Blah blah blah... Code to update user with new username
    // and save changes to DB which is then followed by:

    // Change claim in Auth Context
    this._authorization.RemoveValue(MyClaimType.Username);
    this._authorization.AddValue(MyClaimType.Username, newUsername);

    // At this point, I can see that the Auth Context
    // has been updated with the new username.

    return user;
}
```

#### Change Password

Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model) {
    string oldPassword = model.oldPassword;
    string newPassword = model.newPassword;

    User user = await UserService.GetUserByLogin(this.Authorization.Username, oldPassword);

    // this is where the failure occurs, so I won't 
    // bother writing out the rest.

    // this.Authorization.Username is equal to "oldUsername" 
    // that we saw in the ChangeUsername method.
}
```

Does `this._authorization` in the service not carry back over to `this.Authorization` the controller?
Is `this.Authorization` different for each partial view for some reason?

Comment: and use proper names => ChangeUsernameVM to  ChangeUserNameViewModel or Atleast ChangeUsernameVm

Answer (score 0):

Clear/Reset/logout the user session, Reload the session data info with the new data supplied by the user or from db

Comment: That would require a refresh and an extra database call. Not exactly ideal. The Auth Context is a session variable... shouldn't you just be able to update the variable itself without restarting the session?